# Java Collections not recognized

Tags: java, collections

I'm new in Java and trying the following code on collections.

I'm getting on Eclipse the warnings i commented as WARNING: in the below code.

```
import java.util.*;

public class A {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LinkedHashMap map = new LinkedHashMap();

        // add some values in the map
        map.put("One", "1");
        // WARNING:       
        //      - Type safety: The method put(Object, Object) belongs to the raw type HashMap. References to generic type HashMap<K,V> should be parameterized
        //      - The method put(String, String) is undefined for the type LinkedHashMap

        map.put("Two", "2");
        System.out.println("Map:" + map);

        // get key "Three"
        System.out.println("" + map.get("Two"));  // WARNING:  he method get(String) is undefined for the type LinkedHashMap

        // get key "Five"
        System.out.println("" + map.get("Five"));
    }
}
```

This is a code sample from a site, and supposedly a simple one.

How come am i getting errors? how can i fix them?

i'm new to Java. bear w/me pls.

Comment: Google your warning and you'll get many answers.

Comment: A tutorial you can read to understand what's going on: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/why.html

Comment: The example you saw was probably from before 2004 (when Java 5.0 came out). Collections are now generic.

Comment: @RussellZahniser well - that explains. was a bit freaky. thx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fix all the warnings at once by [properly declaring your map with generics.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html) If you're using Java >=7:

```
Map<String, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
```

otherwise:

```
Map<String, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should use.Its better to use Interface always

```
Map map = new LinkedHashMap();
```

Typesafety In simple I can explain as  If you have a basket of fruit do  you want to store flowers there?
So you should declare as

`Map<String,String> map = new LinkedHashMap<String,String>();` which says my map key is of string type and value if of string type